# BIRT visibility hide if value = string with spaces

Tags: expression, hide, element, birt

I am trying to hide a row in BIRT when a specific value equals a string. It works when the value equals something like 3 or (this_is_the_value) but it does not work when the value equals something like (this is the value) -> a value in the database with multiple words with spaces between them. How do I build the expression that hides the row when a value equals (this is the value) instead of (this_is_the_value)

Any help would be appreciated..

Michel

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose your value with quotes `"this is the value"` and use the double equals sign `==` to compare it to your row.

[image: hideRow]

Comment: Tnx I tried but does not work. I am loading a value in a datafield (varchar). i use type 'string'. For this datafield in the script editor I am setting a variabe on the onCreate event (reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("bulkedit", row["bulkedit"]);). In the row that I want to make (in)visible I am loading the variabele (reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable("bulkedit") in a datafield (type string). I am using this field to declare the visibility rules. As mentioned it does not work. Does this has anything to do with the fact I am using a GlobalVariable or data type?

Comment: @Michel: You should output your global variable in a dynamic Text field for debug reasons. Then you will see, that is has always the value of your first row. Maybe this is the reason for your error. In general this also works with global variables, too.

Comment: Eventually I found out that it had something to do with the datatype. I have changed my form value using only numbers for the value. I created a global variable retrieving it in the table that has conditional visibility, setting the datatype to decimal. In the visibility expression I am using <, >, = 'decimal' This works so I assume my earlier problem was due to the datatype and string values.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, you can hide/show a visual text parameter in an expression like this:
!params[NAME_ID].value